# I keep gettin totalfirst.tofixed(2) is not a function and it directs me to this line

Tags: javascript

```
...var totalFirst = bookFirst+exFirst; totalFirst = totalFirst.toFixed(2);
```

what is wrong with the code?

```
{

var layStakeWin = (backStake*(backOdds-1.0)*(1.0-backCom)+backStake)/(layOdds-layCom);
layStakeWin = layStakeWin.toFixed(2);

var layStakePlace = (backStake*(((backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms)+1)*(1.0-backCom))/(layOdds-layCom);
layStakePlace = layStakePlace.toFixed(2);

var bookFirst = (backStake*(backOdds-1.0)*(1.0-backCom))+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1.0-backCom));
bookFirst = bookFirst.toFixed(2);

var exFirst = 0-(layStakeWin*(layOdds-1.0))-(layStakePlace*((layOdds/placeTerms)-1.0));
exFirst = exFirst.toFixed(2);

var totalFirst = bookFirst+exFirst;
totalFirst = totalFirst.toFixed(2);

var bookStandard = 0-backStake+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1-backCom));
bookStandard = bookStandard.toFixed(2);

var exStandard = (layStakeWin*(1-layCom))-(layStakePlace*(layOdds-1.0));
exStandard = exStandard.toFixed(2);

var totalStandard = bookStandard+exStandard;
totalStandard = totalStandard.toFixed(2);

var bookExtra = 0-backStake+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1.0-backCom));
bookExtra = bookExtra.toFixed(2);

var exExtra = (layStakeWin*(1-layCom))+(layStakePlace*(layOdds-1.0));
exExtra = exExtra.toFixed(2);

var totalExtra = bookExtra+exExtra;
totalExtra = totalExtra.toFixed(2);

var bookNo = 0-backStake-backStake;
bookNo = bookNo.toFixed(2);

var exNo = (layStake*(1.0-layCom))+(layStakePlace*(layOdds-1.0));
exNo = exNo.toFixed(2);

var totalNo = bookNo+exNo;
totalNo = totalNo.toFixed(2);

}
```

Comment: Edit your question down to the *minimum* needed to demonstrate the issue.  We shouldn't have to search your code for "totalFirst".

Comment: Im actually new to this so I dont really know what the minimum would be amy, maybe you can tell me  please lol

Comment: @Cassm did you change it everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that toFixed() returns a string.

To fix this problem, **everywhere** you use toFixed(), wrap it inside the parseFloat() function.

For example,

```
layStakeWin = parseFloat(layStakeWin).toFixed(2);
```

***Please make this change everywhere you use toFixed().***

```
{

var layStakeWin = (backStake*(backOdds-1.0)*(1.0-backCom)+backStake)/(layOdds-layCom);
layStakeWin = parseFloat(layStakeWin).toFixed(2);

var layStakePlace = (backStake*(((backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms)+1)*(1.0-backCom))/(layOdds-layCom);
layStakePlace = parseFloat(layStakePlace).toFixed(2);

var bookFirst = (backStake*(backOdds-1.0)*(1.0-backCom))+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1.0-backCom));
bookFirst = parseFloat(bookFirst).toFixed(2);

var exFirst = 0-(layStakeWin*(layOdds-1.0))-(layStakePlace*((layOdds/placeTerms)-1.0));
exFirst = parseFloat(exFirst).toFixed(2);

var totalFirst = bookFirst+exFirst;
totalFirst = totalFirst.toFixed(2);

var bookStandard = 0-backStake+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1-backCom));
bookStandard = parseFloat(bookStandard).toFixed(2);

var exStandard = (layStakeWin*(1-layCom))-(layStakePlace*(layOdds-1.0));
exStandard = parseFloat(exStandard).toFixed(2);

var totalStandard = bookStandard+exStandard;
totalStandard = totalStandard.toFixed(2);

var bookExtra = 0-backStake+(backStake*(backOdds-1.0)/placeTerms*(1.0-backCom));
bookExtra = parseFloat(bookExtra).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thank you , will let you know if that solved the problem

Comment: Not solved yet , still won't calculate

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Thank you, I will do better to make sure to respond faster